# Equating Coefficients in Partial fractions

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I'm having a hard time figuring out A, B, and C for this problem.

$$  
\frac{8}{y^{3} - 4y}
$$

All I've got so far is

$$  
\frac{A}{y} + \frac{B}{(y+2)} + \frac{C}{(y-2)}
$$
$$
8 = A(y+2)(y-2) + B(y)(y-2) + C(y)(y+2)
$$

Once you get to this point do you just distribute? After that how do you solve for A, B, C?

Comment: the last equation is really an identity. so you sub carefully selected values for $y$ to eliminate as many unknowns as possible. try $y = 0$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug in different values for $y$. For instance, plugging in

- $y=0$ gives us $A(2)(-2) = 8 \implies A=-2$
- $y=-2$ gives us $B(-2)(-4) = 8 \implies B=1$
- $y=2$ gives us $C(2)(4) = 8 \implies C=1$

Answer (score 0):

$$A(y^2-4)+B(y^2-2y)+C(y^2+2y)=(A+B+C)y^2+(2C-2B)y-4A=8$$

So,

$$A+B+C=0\\
2C-2B=0\\
-4A=8.$$